# Nodejs config error

Tags: node.js, config

I have been using config module for half a year in various scripts for almost a year. Now all of a sudden config is throwing an error complaining that I don't have a method watchForConfigFileChanges(); Does anyone know anything about this or how to fix this? I am using node v0.10.31 and the most recent version of config from npm. Am I supposed to add this method somewhere? I am lost. Below is the terminal output:

```
isaacs-air:NU isaacflaum$ node bin/test.js 

/Users/isaacflaum/Code/Forensiq/NU/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:1185
global.NODE_CONFIG.watchForConfigFileChanges();
                   ^
TypeError: Object {

    "reportingDb": {
        "user" : "isaac",
        "password" : "whatIfThisIsActuallyMyPassword?"
    },

    "bingAPI": {
        "user"  : "user",
        "password" : ""
    }

}

 has no method 'watchForConfigFileChanges'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/isaacflaum/Code/Forensiq/NU/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:1185:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/isaacflaum/Code/Forensiq/NU/bin/test.js:17:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Comment: Well, npm just went 2.0 [yesterday or before](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/98131109725/npm-2-0-0). Maybe it has some breaking changes.

Comment: Figured it out, had a bunch of arrays in default.json of the form
`['a', 'b', ...]` - changed to
`["a", "b", ...]` - don't forget those double quotes kids!